# Slow Cross Apply Query Needs Optimization

Tags: sql-server-2016, cross-apply

I have a stored procedure which takes about 4 min to complete. I added some logging and discovered that the reason it is slow is the Cross Apply queries, of which there are 5. Each one takes about 40 seconds to complete. I'm sure there are ways to improve the performance, which I'm hoping someone can help me with. Here is the query:

```
update @Data1
set Open = b.Open_Sum
from @Data1 a
cross apply (Select Count(*) as Open_Sum
from [Data] c
where (c.Sunday > a.Week or c.Sunday is Null)
and c.Project = a.Project
and c.Item = a.Item
and c.IPT = a.IPT
and c.Product = a.Product
and c.Center = a.Center
and c.Name = a.Name
and c.Project  in (select * from SplitParmList(@Project ))
and c.Product in (select * from SplitParmList(@Product  ))
and c.Item in  (select * from SplitParmList(@Item ))
and c.Area in  (select * from SplitParmList(@Area ))
and c.IPT in  (select * from SplitParmList(@IPT ))
and c.Name in  (select * from SplitParmList(@Name ))
and c.Center in  (select * from SplitParmList(@Center ))
and c.Effectivity  in  (select * from SplitParmList(@Effectivity))
and c.Planned in (select * from SplitParmList(@Planned))
and CURRENT = 'Y'
) as b
```

Query Explanation:

1. Populates a table variable (@Data1) with the aggregate count, in this case
   records still open
2. The SplitParmList is a function that parses a parameter passed into the SP. ie. ('a,b,c,d,e')
3. The Data table is indexed

I'm looking for suggestions that may help speed this query up.

**As requested, here is the SplitParmList function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitParmList] (@StringList VARCHAR(MAX))

RETURNS @TableList TABLE( StringLiteral VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartPointer INT, @EndPointer INT
    SELECT @StartPointer = 1, @EndPointer = CHARINDEX(',', @StringList)
    WHILE (@StartPointer < LEN(@StringList) + 1) 
      BEGIN
        IF @EndPointer = 0 
        SET @EndPointer = LEN(@StringList) + 1
        INSERT INTO @TableList (StringLiteral)
        VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@StringList, @StartPointer, @EndPointer - @StartPointer))))
        SET @StartPointer = @EndPointer + 1
        SET @EndPointer = CHARINDEX(',', @StringList, @StartPointer)
      END -- WHILE
    RETURN
END -- FUNCTION
```

**Here is the index:**

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20210222-092308] ON [dbo].[Data]
(
  [Name] ASC,
  [Center] ASC,
  [Project] ASC,
  [Effectivity] ASC,
  [Product] ASC,
  [Drawing] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [dbo]
```

Comment: What is `SplitParmList`? Can you include the definition of the function? Why aren't you using `STRING_SPLIT` or (probably better) a table type parameter?

Comment: *"The Data table is indexed"* Without knowing the definition of the index(es) this doesn't mean a lot; a single clustered index on `Effectivity` is unlikely to help, for example. Can you add their definitions for the question to please.

Comment: That function is going to be *terrible* for performance. Multi-line table value functions are known to perform poorly as are `WHILE` loops, you are using both and have multiple calls to the function; that would bring any well written query to a very slow slog. Why aren't you using `STRING_SPLIT` or a table type parameter, as mentioned?

Comment: Is that your only index? That doesn't look like a good Clustered Index candidate to me; I doubt that all those columns will be always ascending which could mean you suffer fragmentation pretty quickly. What nonclustered indexes do you have?

Comment: @Larnu I wasn't aware of STRING_SPLIT. This function was created a long time ago, and we have just be reusing it. As for indexes, that is the only one on the table.

Comment: I really suggest you get rid of that function; it's not performant. A Tally or XML in an inline table value function would be far better, and a CLR splitter even better. Of course, you have access to `STRING_SPLIT` though, so you should really be using that now.

Comment: Can you please add the actual execution plan to your Post? You can upload it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and add the link. Though Larnu is probably pretty spot on, on where your bottleneck lies.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload the plan because it contains specific details about the database. I sanitized the query above. I changed all of the SplitParmList to STRING_SPLIT and the performance DECREASED. It went from 4:07 min:sec to 6:37 min:sec.

Comment: How many elements are in each delimited parameter?  If you have many elements (10+) then an INNER JOIN on the output of STRING_SPLIT might perform better.

Comment: I added an additional index and have decreased the time by about 30 seconds. The elements can have any number of values. I'll take a look at @JonathanFite suggestion and post back.

Comment: @JonathanFite I tried the inner join and it increased processing time.

Comment: You can sanitize the query plan using SentryOne Plan Explorer. We can't hepl you further without the plan. Also what is the definition for the `@Data1` table variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should use table-valued parameters instead of string-splitting.

First declare a table type, note that it should have a primary key. I usually keep a few standard one-column ones.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList (value varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then the subqueries get transfomred into `(select value FROM @product)` etc. You should also use more obvious table aliases, and use the correct alias on the first line.

Ensure the column in your table type matches the column name that you are querying, and that **includes** `varchar` lengths.

```
update d1
set Open = d.Open_Sum
from @Data1 d1
cross apply (
  Select Count(*) as Open_Sum
  from Data d
  where (d.Sunday > d1.Week or d.Sunday is Null)
  and d.Project = d1.Project
  and d.Item = d1.Item
  and d.IPT = d1.IPT
  and d.Product = d1.Product
  and d.Center = d1.Center
  and d.Name = d1.Name
  and d.Project  in (select value FROM @Project )
  and d.Product in (select value FROM @Product)
  and d.Item in (select value FROM @Item )
  and d.Area in (select value FROM @Area )
  and d.IPT in  (select value FROM @IPT )
  and d.Name in  (select value FROM @Name )
  and d.Center in  (select value FROM @Center )
  and d.Effectivity in (select value FROM @Effectivity)
  and d.Planned in (select value FROM @Planned)
  and d.CURRENT = 'Y'
) as d
```

You are also going to want to sort out the indexing on both `Data` and `@Data1` but it's hard to say what you need without a query plan.

If you still want string-splitting, then just create table variables from the table types, and insert using the `STRING_SPLIT` function.

Comment: I tried table variables and it increased processing time. I'm confused about using TVPs. Are these persistent in the database? Would I need one created for every input parameter? How would I populate them from the input parameters?

Comment: You only need one table type for every possible data type, for example `StringList` and `NStringList` and `IntList`. You need to pass them through from your client application as table valued parameters

Comment: If I understand you, I need to 1. Create the TVP's in the database. 2. Add a declaration of the TVP to the SP (ie. @projects StringList). 3.Pass a table to the StringList typed parameter (i.e. I'm using Angular so, projects: this.criteria.Project != '' ? this.criteria.Project : 'null',).  Is this going to be any faster than using table variables populated from the Split_String?

Comment: Yes you understand the steps correct (but the TVP is the parameter, whose type is a table type). Probably faster, but depends how good the Angular SQL Server driver is. Even if you use table variables, make sure they are indexed (you can just define them like this `DECLARE @Project dbo.StringList;`)

Comment: Thanks. I saw your other comment above. I need to do some more testing.